# Mage::helper('modulename')->__('string') returns Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage_Packagename-modulename_Helper_Data' not found

Tags: configuration, backend

I'm following [this alanstorm tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration/) and when I'm trying to load the backend page I've got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mage_Antonino-banner_Helper_Data' not found

Probably there's some typo or some naming convention error, but I really cannot find it.

> app/code/local/Antonino/Banner/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Antonino_Banner>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Antonino_Banner>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <banner>
                <class>Antonino_Banner_Model</class>
            </banner>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <banner>
                <class>Antonino_Banner_Helper</class>
            </banner>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

And

> app/code/local/Antonino/Banner/etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <antonino_banner translate="label" module="antonino-banner">
            <label>Antonino</label>
            <sort_order>350</sort_order>
        </antonino_banner>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <antoninobanner translate="label" module="antonino-banner">
            <label>Banner Config Options</label>
            <tab>antonino_banner</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>300</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <general translate="label">
                    <label>General</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <choose_category translate="label comment">
                            <label>Choose Category</label>
                            <comment>Select the category to which apply the banner</comment>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>banner/categories</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </choose_category>
                    </fields>
                </general>
                <anothergroup translate="label">
                    <label>Another Group</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </anothergroup>
            </groups>
        </antoninobanner>
        <antoninobannertwo translate="label" module="antonino-banner">
            <label>Another section</label>
            <tab>antonino_banner</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>300</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        </antoninobannertwo>
    </sections>
</config>
```

The error shows when I use the method `Mage::helper('banner')->__('Hello')` in `app/code/local/Antonino/Banner/Model/Categories.php` which code is

```
<?php

class Antonino_Banner_Model_Categories extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value'=>1, 'label'=>Mage::helper('banner')->__('Hello')),
            array('value'=>2, 'label'=>Mage::helper('banner')->__('Goodbye')),
            array('value'=>3, 'label'=>Mage::helper('banner')->__('Yes')),
            array('value'=>4, 'label'=>Mage::helper('banner')->__('No')),
        );
    }

}
```

Someone could pls help me? I really cannot figure out why this is not working. 
Thanks!

Comment: have you  created file `Data.php` at `app/code/local/Antonino/Banner/Helper/` ?

Comment: Yes, here it is:
<?php


class Antonino_Banner_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}

The path is right, I've just checked.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: For some reason, Mage::helper looks for 'Antonino-banner_Helper' instead of 'Antonino_Banner_Helper'

Comment: I think the code in model is fine, just change module="antonino-banner" to module="banner" in your system.xml file

Comment: Show us `app/etc/modules/AntoninoBanner.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the answers, I solved the problem.
I've changend all the

```
<antoninobannertwo translate="label" module="antonino-banner">
```

In to

```
<antoninobanner translate="label" module="banner">
```

Comment: I will thanks.
But without your help, probably I could not make it.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There are a typo in: `app/code/local/Antonino/Banner/etc/system.xml`

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
>  <config>
>    <tabs>
>      <antonino_banner translate="label" module="antonino-banner">
>                                                         ^
> ```
>
> And this is repeated in:
>
> ```
> <antoninobanner translate="label" module="antonino-banner">
>                                                   ^
> ```
>
> and in:
>
> ```
> <antoninobannertwo translate="label" module="antonino-banner">
>                                                      ^
> ```

should be

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <config>
   <tabs>
    <antonino_banner translate="label" module="antonino_banner">
                                                       ^
```

Comment: Now it works! Thank you so much.
And especially thank also to Piyush who found the error too.

Thanks everyone